# Gas oven not getting enough gas

Tags: gas, oven, clog

My gas oven ignites but not enough gas is flowing through.
I was able to clean all stovetop burners with a pin to unclog the gas inlets.  I'm hoping that's what's wrong with the oven, but I do not know how or where the little gas hole is, in the oven.
Can anyone can help please?

Comment: Need a lot more info.  Propane or Natural Gas?  Is this a new issue, or has this always been happening?  Any change to your gas supply or maintenance on gas piping?  Why do you think not enough gas is flowing through?

Comment: Gas burners shouldn't ever need cleaning out or unclogging under normal circumstances, so that is a concern right up front if you've had to do that.

Comment: Food spills and vaporized grease over time could lead to clogged burner orifaces, also particulate matter in the pipes. they sell cleaning wires for these for a reason. Improper use could enlarge the oriface beyond the proper value.